# whats wrong with eclipse configuration for android?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a adt bundle for android, which contains sdk of version 17. unziped it and i can easily use the eclipse inside the bundle without any issue.

Then i copied only the sdk directory to c drive and also kept the eclipse juno folder in that drive. installed plugns for eclipse from *ADT - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse*. But whenever i am trying to create an android project its showing error.

Thought it was for the appcompact support library issue. So, made a library project and added to my another newly created project. Now when i am cleaning up my projects and building up its showing errors:

```
                    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:107: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:126: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:143: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:132: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:146: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:154: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:158: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:164: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:168: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:172: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:174: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:55 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.

    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:132: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:146: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:154: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:158: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:164: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:168: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:172: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:174: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:352: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:359: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:202: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:212: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:205: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:219: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] 
    [2014-12-19 00:44:56 - kk] C:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:223: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
```

its showing errors in the library project of appcompact. in the subfolders of res folder - value-v21,value-v14 etc. is it because i dont have api 14,21 installed?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this installing api 21 from SDK manager and in the library project propiertes change target to api 21 (android 5.0.1)